# Null-conditional operator always true in if statement when should be false

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0

When using a null-conditional operator the first if statement will always output True, however the second if statement will output False when using parentheses. Why is the first if statement True?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Test { Boolean = true };

            //True
            if (test?.Boolean ?? true && 1 == 2)
                Console.WriteLine("True");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("False");

            //False
            if ((test?.Boolean ?? true) && 1 == 2)
                Console.WriteLine("True");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("False");
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public bool? Boolean { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mm8 sorry, fixed. Vladimir Arustamian answer is correct still. https://ideone.com/2IRkM1

Comment: I've just checked and it **does** print false/false (-> https://ideone.com/0nFM9S). Please update your code and show the exact case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x ?? y – returns x if it is non-null; otherwise, returns y.
```

test?.Boolean is x in the first case and (true && 1 == 2) is y.